# How do I write a CD/DVD from the shell to save emails etc?

Tags: command-line, login, files, dvd

Was wondering if there is a simple way to save emails, etc... to a CD/DVD from terminal when the upgrade to ubuntuu 14.04 has delivered an icon and bar-less desktop with a program  error message?  Needless to say, I did not make a backup (not that I know how to).  The information is not that important, but would like to learn how to do a few things in Linux, other than getting stuck in log-in loops.

Comment: Which email program are you using? Do you use POP3 or IMAP to read mail? (IMAP keeps the mail on the server normally)

Comment: So, why am I allowed to comment in my own question, but not in other threads?  I forgot about that--the account is MSLive account; I can check and see if they are stored in the cloud!!!  How wonderful.  I don't really want to do a clean install after an upgrade, but the upgrade didn't take well.  My Dad's computer, not too much of importance, though.

Comment: Just boot from a live CD and copy your files to an external drive.

Comment: The live iso does work (boot), but need to know how to access the user account with the proper permissions, if I remember correctly.don't go into the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Burning CD/DVD from terminal

The tool to burn a CD or DVD from the command line is [`growisofs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/growisofs.1.html). The man page shows only part of the options, because some are forwarded to a subcommand, that is used by `growisofs`: [`genisoimage`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/genisoimage.1.html)

For example, of the command line to burn the home directory to a DVD (assuming it is not too large), `growisofs -Z /dev/sr0 -r -J /home/username`, the options `-Z /dev/sr0` are documented in `man growisofs`, and `-r -J /home/username` are described in `man genisoimage`

See http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1089 for some examples.

### Backup of email

If you use IMAP to read mail, not POP3, there is a good chance that the mail is stored on the mail server, and you only have a copy. (IMAP keeps the mail on the server normally, but you can also move mail to a local folder)

If you use Thunderbird, your mails are stored in something like `~/.thunderbird/*.default` usually, as part of the thunderbird profile.

A backup of this contains account settings too.

If you want to backup independant of the format of thunderbird, there is the thunderbird addon "ImportExportTools" that can be used to export mails to single files, for example, to have a more flexible backup.

Comment: Looks pretty complicated.  I might try something with it, though.  My Dad's emails seem to be in the cloud and the only other stuff are his casual game histories and web browsing histories . . . , not too important.  I've tried nearly all of the command lines that people have thrown out on the blank desktop threads; nothing seems to work.  I can't vote for any of these answers, sorry and thank you.

Comment: Hmm... if you're not sure there may be relevant data, but the home directory is new or almost empty, you could keep the full home directory on a CD, then you're safe. What does `du -sh ~` say?

Comment: du -sh ~ (returns) 1.1 G /home/username.

Comment: Ok, so it's not empty, but that can all be browser caches etc. It fits on a DVD, and there are a few hundred bytes that are important, somewhere ;)

Comment: Yes, I looked @ my DVD to see how much it would hold, but growisofs does not look simple.  I've got a couple of books and what you have given me and maybe I can piece something together that will copy the home directory to disk and then I can try an install from my live iso that MAY work better than the upgrade; then copying the dvd to the OS.  Piece of cake for someone familiar with the protocols.

Comment: I can not try it, but the first variant of the command looks right: `growisofs -Z /dev/sr0 -r -J /home/username`. The device may be `/dev/sr1` instead of `/dev/sr0`, you can try. (The `-r` and `-J` are to save full filenames)

Comment: I think that I will try it; there is also an admin account that I think will have less in it than the owner's account, so will be using two writes to the disk? Returned 38 Mb. Can both writes be contained in one command line--from what I have seen of Linux, they can?

Comment: The account of root normally does not contain many configuration files or so, because it's not really used as a user. Use `ls /root` to see whether there are some relevant files. If there was some tricky configuration, or driver problem, the files needed to fix it could be there. I guess it's empty, but don't count on that. (If there is system configuration (manual changes) you want to keep, pack '/etc' too.)

Comment: (returns) desktop documents downloads music NTR pictures public templates videos                I don't recall there to be a problem to the administrator other than a bad ram stick.  PC has Radeon onboard graphics (4200) and AMD Athlon 64 duo CPU--possibly a problem in the upgrade.

Comment: Most or all are default directories, may be empty. (`NTR` is not default)

Comment: NTR as in remote access? Used Team Viewer and another one, don't recall.

Comment: I do not know what NTR is - it's just a directory name you listed that does not exist by default.

Comment: Volker, growisofs is not in any of my books (must be a secret or my books are old).

Comment: `growisofs` is a command that combines the features to create cd image (*.iso file) and to burn that file to a CD. Older programs for this are `cdrecord` and `mkisofs`, now there's `genisoimage`, that can be combined with `wodim`, or used indirectly by `growisofs`, which does the job of `wodim` too.

Comment: Why is genisoimage  even more complex than growisofs when growisofs is dependent upon genisoimage?  Does growisofs attempt to alleviate/temper the requirements of genisoimage?

Comment: `growisofs` just uses `genisoimage` - so if you see `genisoimage` as part of `growisofs`, it includes the complexity of `genisoimage`, and is more complex. If you see the commands as cooperating components, `genisoimage` is more complex. It's complex because it needs to handle all CD filesystem variants since the CD was invented.

Comment: I tried " sudo growisof -Z/dev/sr0 -r -J /home/username " or (or "-Z  /dev"), was given somekind error messages, sorry, I didn't record.  Then used live DVD of Trusty Tahr "try me" to operational desktop and did reinstall of 14.04.1 LTS over the upgrade.  The desktop now operational, but lost GUEST account after (2 boots?); didn't get the administration account that is on separate partition along with owner's files activated with reinstall.       I tried growisofs with new user's account while logged in, and wrote to disk--most probably most recent home files and not from separate partition?

Comment: I am getting off topic, so should maybe close this, although I have another PC with failed upgrade that was not backedup, and may try growisofs on it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what email software you are using, for example on my Thunderbird setup I copy the [profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird#Linux_and_Unix) and rsync it from time to time to separate folder (with thunderbird is turned off) and then that folder I backup to external media when needed.